# when i do the gradient descent the value is inflation

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, linear-gradients, gradient-descent

In this code, I created a Gradient Descent algorithm to optimize Theta0 and Theta1, and each time it is checked: Is the cost of the function with the new Theta smaller? --- then set this Theta.
But the first time I find that the new theta makes a bigger cost, what should I do?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.array([460 ,232, 315, 178])
y = np.array([2104, 1416, 1534, 852])

class LinearFormala :
  def __init__ (self):
    self.theta_0 = np.random.rand()
    self.theta_1 = np.random.rand()
  def calc_y (self,x):
    return self.theta_0 + ( self.theta_1 * x )
  def cost (self,th,X,y):
    pred_y = np.array( [th[0]+(th[1]*x) for x in X] )
    return np.absolute(y - pred_y).mean()
  def GD (self, x_s, y_s, lr=0.001):
    optm_th0 = True
    optm_th1 = True
    tmp_th_0 = 0
    tmp_th_1 = 0
    for x,y in zip(x_s,y_s):
      if optm_th0:
        tmp_th_0 = self.theta_0 - lr * self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1], x_s,y_s)
        print('here',self.cost([tmp_th_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s), self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s))
        if self.cost([tmp_th_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s) < self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s):
          self.theta_0 = tmp_th_0
        else:
          optm_th0=False
      if optm_th1:
        tmp_th_1 = self.theta_1 - lr * self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1], x_s,y_s) * x
        print('here2',self.cost([self.theta_0,tmp_th_1],x_s,y_s), self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s))
        if self.cost([self.theta_0,tmp_th_1],x_s,y_s) < self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s):
          self.theta_1 = tmp_th_1
        else:
          optm_th1=False


model = LinearFormala()
print('Thetas :',[model.theta_0 , model.theta_1])
plt.plot(x,[model.calc_y(i) for i in x], label='Before Training')
plt.plot(x,y,'ro',label='Real Data')
plt.legend(loc='best')
model.GD(x,y)
print('Thetas :',[model.theta_0 , model.theta_1])
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand everything on your post so, I'll try to assume some things, and you'll tell if I am wrong sometimes ... So first, the gradient descent algorithm's goal is to minimise a function. So I guess the function you try to minimise is the loss function of your Linearformula class.

The main mistake I see is that, to adapt your parameters self.theta_0 and self.theta_1, you use your cost function instead of using the gradient of the cost function ... the formula to adapt your parameters of the function is :
x_k+1 = x_k − lr * ∇f(x_k) and you did :
x_k+1 = x_k − lr * f(x_k)

so

```
tmp_th_0 = self.theta_0 - lr * self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1], x_s,y_s)
```

becomes :

```
tmp_th_0 = self.theta_0 - lr * self.gradcost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1], x_s,y_s)[0]
```

and

```
tmp_th_1 = self.theta_1 - lr * self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1], x_s,y_s) * x
```

becomes :

```
tmp_th_1 = self.theta_1 - lr * self.gradcost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1], x_s,y_s)[1]
```

with :

```
def gradcost(self,th,X,y):
    pred_y = [[],[]]
    pred_y = np.array(pred_y)
    pred_y[0] = [1 + (th[1]*x) for x in X]
    pred_y[1] = [th[0] + x for x in X]
    mean_1 = mean(pred_y[0])
    mean_2 = mean(pred_y[1])
    return np.array([[mean_1],[mean_2]])
```

you will have defined in your Linearformula class

And with the gradient descent algorithm, you don't need conditions like

```
if self.cost([tmp_th_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s) < self.cost([self.theta_0,self.theta_1],x_s,y_s):
      self.theta_0 = tmp_th_0
```

you just adapt your parameter ...

And last but not least, you need a while loop because without it you will only adapt the parameters once as the gradient descent algorithm is an iterative algorithm. And to stop your while loop : either you get a small enough ||∇f(x_k)||
(||∇f(x_k)|| < 1e-3 for example) or you reach an itermax value of 1e3 or 1e4 iterations (another value you need to define before).

I hope I helped you, don't hesitate if you don't understand something, and good luck for the following of you coding.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).